# How does electric current generate thermal energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, energy

How does free electrons moving through a wire cause random vibrational motion of the positive ions?

Answer (score 2):

Well, those electrons tend to run into things, both other electrons and the atoms, a process called scattering.  Scattering off the ions can generate phonons (lattice vibrations), and that transfers energy from the electrons to the lattice.  Similarly, phonons can scatter off electrons.  In thermal equilibrium the rates are the same forward and backward.
If you are wondering why electrons would interact with the lattice atoms, you already pointed out the lattice atoms are positively charged, so there is a force between the electrons and ions.

Answer (score 0):

From a thermodynamic point of view, when you have no current in the wire, the free electrons in the wire are, for the most part, not moving around very much in a random fashion. Temperature is the sum of the random, vibrational motion of the particles in a system. Once you put a current through the wire, ie introduce an electric potential, you set the free electrons  in the wire into motion. It's like trying to run down a very populated hallway. If everyone is standing still ( no current in the wire ) you're not that likely to collide with someone ( generating random vibrational motion; heat ), whereas if everyone is also trying to get somewhere via this hallway ( current in the wire ), you're almost certainly going to collide with people, and statistically, a lot. So the "collisions" of the electrons against the positive ions ( which there also exists a potential between ) when a current is pushed through the wire is what causes heating.